# FCM-I have the server key but I am not remembering the login details to FCM. How will i get details from serverkey?

Tags: java, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have done a project with FCM Push Notification feature. In my java I put the server key from FCM for easily pushing the notification. This was 2 years before and now I am not remembering the Gmail I used to create the FCM account.
Is there any way I can get any information from my server key?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reaching out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) since this is about ownership issue. It’ll be challenging to help you on a public forum without going into project-specific details. The support channel can offer personalized help.